# asp.net MVC cookie is null while page is redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating creating cookie in PageB and while click PageA link here it is redirecting to PageA. But I'm not seeing cookie in PageA. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PageA()
        {             

            if (Request.Cookies["bCookie"] != null) { 
           //code
            }    
            return ActionResult(View(PageA));
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PageB(Model bCookieM)
        {
            HttpCookie bCookie= new HttpCookie("bCookie");
            bCookie.Value = bCookieM.ToString();

            Response.Cookies.Add(bCookie);                      

            return View(PageB);
        }
```

Comment: Try setting expiration date? Use `bCookie.Expires` and set date in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs: If you do not set the cookie's expiration, the cookie is created but it is not stored on the user's hard disk. Instead, the cookie is maintained as part of the user's session information. When the user closes the browser, the cookie is discarded.

To make the cookie persistent (for 24 hours). Do something like this:

```
Response.Cookies["userName"].Value = userName;
Response.Cookies["userName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

HttpCookie bCookie = new HttpCookie("bCookie");
bCookie.Value = bCookieM.ToString();
bCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies.Add(bCookie);
```

Comment: By default expiry date is 1 day. I'm seeing in browser. Anyway I've added but still it is null.

Comment: @user3194721 You can only read the cookie once the browser has sent back the request. You need to initiate this request.

Comment: yes I'm reading like below if (Request.Cookies["bCookie"] != null) { 
           //code
            }

Comment: @user3194721 if you are redirecting to pageA, you are not getting a request from pageA - you are just sending a response. It is in the request that you read the cookie.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get exactly. Can you please give me sample code?

Comment: The request is what is sent to the server from the client. You just need to go to that page from the client.

Comment: Here there is no server communication. I'm creating cookie in one page and want to read in another page.(I don't want to use any sessions)

Comment: I find the issue. I'm running application locally. So it is http request. I need to disable secure.
   customerCookie.Secure = false;